# how to use the vertices data or how it affect the model

Tags: modeling

how do I use this crease in 2.8[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it to control if and how much bevel you want on specific edges on your model. Add a Bevel Modifier and set the Limit Method to Weight.

[image]

Comment: yeah thanks. have found it. I think this one is for edge. so I turned on the (only vertices ) at the bevel modifier and is working now.